# Enforce Cache-Control in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

My endpoint method generates a different response for each invocation regardless of the parameter list. I often see my client call the endpoint with the same parameter list, and the front end instance returns a cached response.

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiMethod#cacheControl()) I read that ApiMethod#cacheControl has been deprecated. On the other hand, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#api_api-scoped_annotations) says that the @Api-scopped annotation @ApiCacheControl has not been implemented yet so adding the following makes no difference.

```
cacheControl = @ApiCacheControl(
        type = ApiCacheControl.Type.NO_CACHE
    )
```

To make things easier, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiCacheControl) also says that

> public @interface ApiCacheControl
>
> Annotation for API cache control configuration. Note that the API frontend itself may act as a caching proxy.

Given the current state of the API what's considered best practice for enforcing cache control?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Would be great if you posted an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching of Google Cloud Endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579015/caching-of-google-cloud-endpoints)